# To use or not to use the database?

Tags: database, api, rest

I set up a REST API (MVC Web API). My iOS (C#/XAMARIN) and Android (C#/XAMARIN) Applications access the REST API. My webpage (C#/MVC) is able to connect the API Server or the database server directly. My question is: Should I choose the API or the SQL Server for my Web application? All applications are using the same C# class library.

This picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBUgH.jpg shows my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use API for the web application,
because it provides JSON or text format data response and to consume API in html / cshtml page is also good and performance of your web application must increase and if you plan for responsive design for your web application that may be used in any device then it is good to have mvc web api restful web service option.